# Row number of a group within a group in an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to assign a row number to a group, which is under another group in an SSRS 2008 report. This is how my report looks:

Salesman1 - Customer Group1 - Row number 1

```
         Customer Group2 - Row number 2

         Customer Group3 - Row number 3
         ---------------
         ---------------
```

Salesman2 - Customer Group1 - Row number 1

```
       - Customer Group2 - Row number 2

       - Customer Group3 - Row number 3
```

As you can see above, the outer group is the Salesman Group and the inner group is the Customer Group. I want to assign a serial number/row number to the Customer Group.

I have tried a lot of runningvalue functions and rownumber functions but nothing seems to work. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select ..., ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY yourGroupID) ....,

Comment: Is there something that I can do on the report side? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that you can do it on SSRS side. Not as I know.